# Load JSON File, iterate over entries and edit them in Java

Tags: java, json, file

I am new to the JSON Universe and want to store multiple JSONObjects in a meaningful way in a JSON file. The JSONObjects come as a String formatted in the JSON syntax to the function, with multiple attributes:

- A unique identifier, here java.util.UUID (Universally Unique Identifier)
- Name
- Age
- Comment (Random String)

For example:

```
{"name":"Peter","ID":"bc6fe168-e73f-48c9-b421-ad3c4c424392", "Age":"23","Comment":"I am a new User"}
```

My Idea is, that I load the json file and store the entries in a List. Then I check if the UUID is already in there. If it is not, I will create a new entry at the end of the List, if it is allready in there I will update the other attributes of this entry.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void updateFile(String user) {

    /* String to JSONObject */
    JSONObject newUser = new JSONObject(content);

    /* Load JSON File */
    String content = readFile("C:\\localProjects\\list.json");

    /* Add or update "newUser" */
    if(boolean isNew = containsID(getID(newUser),content))
        content.append(user);
    else 
        updateUser(newUser);

}
```

This method works for my usecase but it does not look very efficient for me and is not really an OOP approach. It also is not very robus, for example if I add a new user with a name which is used as an UUID in a different entry it edits the wrong user instead of adding him as a new one.

Are there functions that could help me easily like:
Load existing JSON as a JSON-List, iterate over the JSON Objects in the Object, edit specific Variables?

Comment: Why you don't create pojo object User and convert it with json.

Comment: @ohlec, we never should correct the typos in the question code, only in the text. It could be relevant to the error that the OP has.

Comment: You have a typo in your heading. Looks not professional (too short to edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a tool like [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7), you could

1. Create a proper POJO `User.java`, you could even use JsonNode
2. Read each user into your java object
3. Store each user into a `HashMap` using the Identifier as Key
4. Write list to, e.g. `standard out`

**Example**

This example reads an array of users to `JsonNode` objects. The `ID` field is accessed via [JsonPointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) syntax.

```
@Test
public void json3() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    Map<String, JsonNode> store = new HashMap<>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode users = mapper.readValue(
                    "[{\"name\":\"Peter\",\"ID\":\"bc6fe168-e73f-48c9-b421-ad3c4c424392\", \"Age\":\"23\",\"Comment\":\"I am a new User\"},{\"name\":\"jschnasse\",\"ID\":\"bc6fe168-e73f-48c9-b421-ad3c4c424393\", \"Age\":\"well\",\"Comment\":\"I am a fun User\"}]",
                    JsonNode.class);
    users.forEach((user) -> {
        String id = user.at("/ID").asText();
        if (!store.containsKey(id)) {
            store.put(id, user);
        } else {
            /* Do something else */
        }
    });
    System.out.println(toString(store.values()));
}

public String toString(Object obj) {
    try (StringWriter w = new StringWriter();) {
        new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).writeValue(w, obj);
        return w.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

*Prints*

```
[ {
  "name" : "jschnasse",
  "ID" : "bc6fe168-e73f-48c9-b421-ad3c4c424393",
  "Age" : "well",
  "Comment" : "I am a fun User"
}, {
  "name" : "Peter",
  "ID" : "bc6fe168-e73f-48c9-b421-ad3c4c424392",
  "Age" : "23",
  "Comment" : "I am a new User"
} ]
```

Comment: Works almost as intended. But what if I would like to store the JSON objects locally as a json file, which should get updated everytime the function gets called with a different content? Can I load the File with something like: `Map<String, JsonNode> store = loadJSONFile("C:\\Path\myFile.json");`

Comment: Look (and upvote) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740360/1485527 on how about loading and storing json to a file. Note: All json data can be seen as of type `Map<String,Object>` this is why you can apply the code directly to your case.