# How to write a Map object to a file

Tags: java, nio

I want to write to a file from a `Map` object.  Here is my attempt.

```
try {
    stuMap.put(student.getId(), student);
    Path file = Paths.get("student.txt");  // to create the file 
    Files.write(file, stuMap, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));  // try to save in the file 
    /*  fileReaderWriter.createFileIn_NIO(stuMap);*/
    try {
        fileReaderWriter.createFileIn_NIO(stuMap);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("file not saved");
    }
    return true;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("not stored in Map");
    return false;
}
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: You can write to a file with no problem if your Student class has a proper toString method.  This code is not good.  Print a stack trace or pass the exception along; don't write a message to System.out.  That's less information than a stack trace.  Returning true or false doesn't help a user handle the issue.

Comment: there is half a dozen different ways to put an object graph on disk. look at serialisation. look at xml format. look at json format. etc. This question is too broad and we can't reply.

Comment: Should the file be human-readable? Is your map serializable?

Comment: Should it be possible to read the file and get the same object back?  Should it be possible to read the file in some other program language?  The fact that none of these things is mentioned in the Question contributes to it being Too Broad.

Comment: Simple: you first have to clarify your requirements. You can write all kinds of stuff into files. Whatever you do is fine. It only gets tricky if you ever want to *read* what was written there. So that is the thing you have to clarify first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple variant to solve the problem is to use Gson library:

```
    String str = new Gson().toJson(yourMap);
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try(FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        file.createNewFile();
        stream.write(str.getBytes());
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("can't write to file");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tools like [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7) to write java maps out as json and read it in as map. As others have mentioned, this is only one possible way.

**Full working Read/Write Example**

```
@Test
public void loadMapFromFileAndSaveIt(){
    Map<Object, Object> map = loadMap("map.json");
    map.put("8", "8th");
    map.remove("7");
    save(map,"/path/to/map2.txt");
}

private Map<Object, Object> loadMap(String string) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try (InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("map.json")) {
        return mapper.readValue(in, HashMap.class);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void save(Map<Object, Object> map,String path) {
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(path)) {
        out.println(toString(map));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public String toString(Object obj) {
    try (StringWriter w = new StringWriter();) {
        new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).writeValue(w, obj);
        return w.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

If the file `map.json` on your classpath contains

```
{
 "1":"1th",
 "2":"2th",
 "3":"3th",
 "4":"4th",
 "5":"5th",
 "6":"6th",
 "7":"7th"
}
```

The code above will modify it and write it to a file `/path/to/map2.txt` that will contain

```
{
  "1" : "1th",
  "2" : "2th",
  "3" : "3th",
  "4" : "4th",
  "5" : "5th",
  "6" : "6th",
  "8" : "8th"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is concept in java for saving state of object and retrieve it back later called 'Serialization'.
To Write Object

```
File fileToSaveObject=new File("path");
Object objectToSave=new Object();

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileToSaveObject);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

out.writeObject(objectToSave); // It will save 'objectToSave' in given file

out.close();
fileOut.close();
```

To Read Object

```
File fileToReadObject=new File("path");
Object objectToRead;

FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileToReadObject);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

objectToRead= (Object) in.readObject();  // It will return you the saved object

in.close();
fileIn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

yourMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(
            outputFile, key + ", " + value + "\n", true);
});
```